# Web app manifest: Downloaded file was empty or corrupted

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, favicon, homescreen, web-app-manifest

I am developing a web app with react and want to include my own icon as icon I can click on my iPhone home screen (after clicking "Add to home screen in Safari"). You can find a Beta version here: https://konekto-5gtxy7fpu.now.sh/

I have googled and tried different options for hours but could not fix the problem. Thus, I am looking for your support.

The following is the relevant snippet from the index.html file:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Konekto" />

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/_icons/apple-icon.png" />
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/_icons/apple-icon-57x57.png"
  sizes="57x57"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-60x60.png"
  sizes="60x60"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-72x72.png"
  sizes="72x72"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-76x76.png"
  sizes="76x76"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-114x114.png"
  sizes="114x114"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-120x120.png"
  sizes="120x120"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-128x128.png"
  sizes="128x128"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-144x144.png"
  sizes="144x144"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-152x152.png"
  sizes="152x152"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-180x180.png"
  sizes="180x180"
/>
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icons/apple-icon-precomposed.png"
/>

<link
  rel="icon"
  type="image/png"
  sizes="32x32"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon-32x32.png"
/>
<link
  rel="icon"
  type="image/png"
  sizes="16x16"
  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon-16x16.png"
/>
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/site.webmanifest" />
    <link
      rel="mask-icon"
      href="%PUBLIC_URL%/safari-pinned-tab.svg"
      color="#5bbad5"
/>
```

The Manifest.json file looks as follows:

```
{
  "short_name": "Konekto",
  "name": "Konekto Emergency App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "android-chrome-192x192.png",
  "sizes": "192x192",
  "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

I have set up the icons as follows:
[root directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd63X.jpg)
[frontend_mpd/public/icons/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfUXF.jpg)

Thus, I would expect the right icon to be shown on the home screen when newly adding it to the iPhone homescreen, but only a screenshot of the app is shown and in the Chrome developer mode -> Application->Installability following is shown: "Downloaded icon was empty or corrupted".

When running it locally, following is shown: [App Manifest Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtObS.jpg)

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Your host is returning this file as HTML (your index.html). Do a view source. Most odd. Are you sure that you did not save your index.html as the .png? https://konekto-5gtxy7fpu.now.sh/android-chrome-192x192.png

Comment: If you open just this file locally with a web browser, does it show the image?  If not, if you open that file with a text editor, does it show html?

Comment: What do you mean with "did I save my index.html as the .png"? The fact is that if I open it locally, I cannot test "add to home screen". However, in Chrome Inspect->Application, sometimes it shows the picture next to "icons", but I always get the warning: downloaded item was empty or corrupted

Comment: If you open just this file locally with a web browser (not with the app), does it show the image? If not, if you open that file with a text editor, does it show html?  (android-chrome-192x192.png)

Comment: Go to this URL for your image in a web browser and right click>view source. When I do that I see HTML. What do you see? https://konekto-5gtxy7fpu.now.sh/android-chrome-192x192.png

Comment: You are right, it opens as html. Do you have an idea why it might be the case that it does not open as png file?

Comment: Most likely you did a save and used the wrong name. Sounds crazy but I still occasionally do that after decades of programming.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file on your server? If so, have you changed anything in that? I just took another look this morning and no matter the URL, your website is returning that HTML. i.e.  https://konekto-5gtxy7fpu.now.sh/garbage.html

Comment: Hm ok I am not sure what you mean. What do I have do differently? Btw I adjusted the text to show what is output when I run it local: "No matching service worker detected. You may need to to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the Manufest"

Comment: I am not sure about the .htaccess file but I just asked my team